# Is there any way to get the key type of a SecKey?

Tags: ios, swift, keychain, seckeyref

Given a [SecKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/seckey), is there any way to infer its type (e.g. whether it is `kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA` or `kSecAttrKeyTypeEC`)?

I see [SecKeyGetTypeID()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1395190-seckeygettypeid), but it is unclear to me what key object this function operates on as it accepts no parameters.

Comment: This may be what you are looking for: https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA/blob/master/Source/SwiftyRSA.swift#L39.

Comment: @MartinR, perfect. You can answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can retrieve the `kSecAttrKeyType` from the key and check if it is `kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA` (or `kSecAttrKeyTypeEC`). Example (taken from [SwiftyRSA](https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA/blob/master/Source/SwiftyRSA.swift#L39)):

```
func isRSAKey(seckey: SecKey) -> Bool {
    guard let attributes = SecKeyCopyAttributes(seckey) as? [CFString: Any],
        let keyType = attributes[kSecAttrKeyType] as? String else {
            return false
    }

    let isRSA = keyType == (kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA as String)
    return isRSA
}
```